# Android - How to Align Symbols in TextView to center

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` where the static text is `SIGN IN >` . I am trying to align the `Greater than Symbol` to center of the other characters, but the symbol is always `aligned bottom` to the other alphabets.

I tried setting `android:textAlignment` as `center`, `gravity` for `TextView` , but no effect. Any idea?

See the screenshot. I highlighted the height.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might unfortunately be a problem with the Font and not with the TextView element. You most likely cannot get the vertical alignment of ">" to change with out messing with the rest of the text. If you really need it to align, create a separate TextView for ">" and play with its alignment until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:gravity="center_vertical"`